# Make moderators edit and close threads instead of deleting them

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, moderators

My idea is: if a thread has prohibited content, the thread should be edited (by removing all content and replacing with something like "moderator edit" on the title, content and tags) instead of deleting it. This applies to all types of prohibited or violating content.

Comment: Not, because this also applies to posts with inappropriate language, posts in other languages, etc.

Comment: What value is there to leaving (possibly extremely offensive) white noise lying around? You've told us what you want, but *why* do you think this is necessary or even a good idea?

Comment: I have seen several forums doing this, for instance XDA Developers.

Comment: Diamond moderators are humans and it's not good for their mental health to curate offensive drivel day after day.  They'll probably say "[moderator edit] that" and give up.

Comment: And what reason do you see for keeping a bunch of "moderator edit" questions around in a library of questions and answers? Does your local library also have empty book covers lying around?

Comment: How would you edit [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341147/how-does-keto-crush-work) to make it on topic?

Answer (score 12):

> ...if a thread has prohibited content, the thread should be edited (by removing all content and replacing with something like "moderator edit" on the title, content and tags) instead of deleting it.

1. Currently when content is flagged 6 times, it's [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).  In this way, the offensive content is removed faster than if it had to wait for a diamond moderator.  This minimizes its harm.  Also, it indicates to anyone who posts offensive content: it's not going to last long.

This is a soft deletion, as [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341144/351283) highlights, so it's possible for high-rep users to see the edit history, etc.

2. It's already possible even for non-(diamond moderator) users to ***edit*** posts to achieve this goal:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly **self-regulating**, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> <sub>[A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation)</sub>

3. Diamond moderators are human volunteers, and probably don't want to waste their time curating offensive content.  Perhaps they'd rather spend time with their family.
4. Merely replacing offensive content with "[moderator edit]" adds noise which Stack Exchange strives to minimize, and the offensive content remains accessible through viewing the post's history (and thus is still harmful).

Diamond moderators can [suspend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) users who repeatedly post offensive content.

Answer (score 1):

Content is seldom *deleted* from a Stack Exchange site.  It's often just hidden from view if it is deleted in the conventional way.

The only time content is actually *removed* is if it's harmful or actively detrimental and shouldn't be shown to others after it's been dealt with.

Once you get 10K+ rep on a specific network site, you can see the deleted posts yourself, unless they have indeed been permanently removed from the site.

Comment: The official term I think you mean in the second paragraph is "redacted": revision history is erased; not even mods can see the pre-redacted version - which is generally used for PII, not "regular" offensive content. Usually spammy or offensive text is just red-flag deleted, which only adds a warning link for 10k-ers, but doesn't permanently remove or prevent them from viewing it.